# DOMPDF pagination in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, pagination, dompdf

I have a problem using barryvdh's DOMPDF plugin for Laravel (5.3), the problem is with pagination in the generated PDF file, for some reason when my data (in a table) is too long the second page never comes up, instead, the content gets stuck at the top of the page.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have used barryvdh's plugin before with Laravel (5.2) and the pagination worked fine.

I have attached two images one with the wrong pagination using Laravel 5.3 and another with the correct pagination from the project using Laravel 5.2

[wrong pdf pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsFSp.png),
[correct pdf pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7O2c.png)

and this is how I am calling DOMPDF from my controller:

```
public function note($config_params)
{
    $params = explode("-", $config_params); // params['note_id','print_option']
    $note = SaleNote::get_ById($params[0]);
    $note_detail = SaleNoteItem::get_ByNote($params[0]);
    $totals = SaleNoteItem::get_TotalsByNote($params[0]);
    $company = Company::get_ById(session('company'));

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('movements.sales.note-pdf', [
        'note' => $note,
        'note_detail' => $note_detail,
        'totals' => $totals,
        'company' => $company,
        'hide_client' => $params[1]
    ]);

    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

has anyone faced this issue before? I hope you can help, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this issue, it was because of CSS styles and HTML markup in the view.

More explicity, I had a < main >< / main > tag, and inside this tag, it was the table and all the other content, just removing this tag and adding clear: both; in the parent div fixed the problem.